# Gerrit project with "Rebase if necessary": Gerrit said "Cannot Merge" but manual rebase was okay?

Tags: git, jenkins, gerrit, rebase

We have a gerrit project with "Submit Type" set to "Rebase if necessary".  The auto verification of changes is done with Jenkins build.

When there are concurrent changes (e.g. Changes A and B that both are based on the same parent), when one change (e.g. A) got reviewed, submitted, and merged, the other change (e.g. B) will have a parent that is "Not current"

This part I understand.

What I don't understand is this: if we have already choose the submit type to be "Rebase if necessary", why would Gerrit still say "Cannot Merge"?  Why don't it just rebase B automatically?

In fact, I do see some concurrent changes received the treatment of automatic rebase.  But this does not happen all the time.  Why?

Usually, on the Gerrit Web UI, there will be an orange dot next to B's parent's hash saying "Not current -- rebase possible".  Would there be a case that says "Not current -- rebase NOT possible"?

(If rebase is possible, then why doesn't Gerrit just do it automatically?)

One final question: when the button [Rebase] is pressed, there is a pop up window with title "Code Review - Rebase Change".  And then there is a check box for "Change parent revision" and a text field for "(subject, change number, or leave empty)".  How should we use the checkbox and the text field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Automatic rebase

First check whether your project has content merge enabled at:

```
Projects > List > YOUR-PROJECT > General > Allow content merges = true
```

Then remember that Gerrit is not able of perform the rebase automatically if there are conflicts that have to be resolved manually. In these situations you need to perform the rebase locally, resolve the conflicts and push another patchset to Gerrit.

2) Rebase option

The checkbox is used to choose a different parent revision to be used in the rebase. The default parent revision is:

- If the change does not depend on another open change, it is rebased onto the tip of the destination branch.
- If the change depends on another open change, it is rebased onto the current patch set of that other change.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#rebase).

Comment: Regarding #1: I checked the setting of my project.  It is "INHERITED (true)"

Comment: I added more info to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I could do a manual rebase on the server by just pressing the [Rebase] button.  That is, I did not need to any manual conflict resolutions (that is, manually picking and choosing some conflict segments in any files) to finish the rebase.  So why can't this be done automatically by Gerrit?  In fact Gerrit does this sometimes but not always -- part of my question is to known what condition Gerrit will do it.

Comment: You use "rebase if necessary" here and I never faced a situation like that, I mean everytime "Cannot Merge" is displayed, it's impossible to use the "Rebase" button. What is your Gerrit version?

Comment: Version of Gerrit is 2.13.2

Comment: Uhm... we have 2.14.3. I didn't find anything relevant between them... It's seems to be a bug only in a special situation, like this one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=5809

Comment: Umm ... okay.  By the way, I am using Chrome not Safari so the symptom is not exactly the same as in the bug 5809.

Comment: Ok, it was just an example.